# Can you use ALTER and AUTO_INCREMENT in hibernate SQL (HQL) in Java?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I've been surfing the internet and can't find an answer to my specific question. I'm using Struts 1.x and Hibernate SQL to run my SQL queries. The problem i'm having is with this:

```
Session ses = factory.getCurrentSession();
ses.createSQLQuery("ALTER TABLE ZeeCallSp AUTO_INCREMENT = :id").setParameter("id", 1).executeUpdate();
```

This gives me this error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query
```

I've tried different ways and still get same error such as:

```
String hql = "ALTER TABLE ZeeCallSp AUTO_INCREMENT = 1";
SQLQuery sqlQuery = ses.createSQLQuery(hql);
sqlQuery.executeUpdate();
```

Another one:

```
String hql = "ALTER TABLE ZeeCallSp AUTO_INCREMENT = :id";
Query query = ses.createQuery(hql);
query.setInteger("id", 1);
query.executeUpdate();
```

So what I need to do is, is to reset the auto increment value back to 1 after I have deleted all the records in my table.

What is the correct way of doing it?

EDIT:

I'm deleting my records in the table first by running this (works perfectly):

```
public void deleteAllRecordsInTableZeeCallSp() {
    try {
        Session ses = factory.getCurrentSession();
        ses.createQuery("delete from ZeeCallSp").executeUpdate();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new EJBException("Could not delete record.");
    }
}
```

Then just after that I'm running this which give me the could not execute native bulk manipulation... error at query.executeUpdate();

```
public void resetAutoIncrementForTableZeeCallSp() {
    try {
        Session ses = factory.getCurrentSession();

        Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();      

        Query query=ses.createSQLQuery("ALTER TABLE ZeeCallSp AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
        query.executeUpdate();  //could not execute native bulk manipulation        

        tx.commit();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        throw new EJBException("Could not delete record.");
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should delete all the records from the table 'ZeeCallSp'.
Later on, use the below code

```
import org.hibernate.Query;

Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();

Query query=session.createSQLQuery("ALTER TABLE ZeeCallSp AUTO_INCREMENT = 1");
query.executeUpdate();
tx.commit();
session.close();
```

Then  insert some records, it should work fine!

**Updated Code**: The delete operation is not completed yet, till you commit the transaction.

```
public void deleteAllRecordsInTableZeeCallSp() {
try {

    Session ses = factory.getCurrentSession();
    Transaction tx=ses.beginTransaction();
    ses.createQuery("delete from ZeeCallSp").executeUpdate();
    tx.commit(); 
    ses.close();      
}
catch (Exception e) {
    log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    throw new EJBException("Could not delete record.");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this reply. I have deleted all records successfully. But once I get to that excecuteUpdate like you suggested it gave me this error:
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute native bulk manipulation query

Comment: please use transaction while updating/inserting values from DB using hibernate. check the updated code.

Comment: can you please share the entire code, the one i said to update with?

Comment: Please check update code below "Edit:" in the original post

Comment: Which database are you using? also do a database server restart, try by adding ses.close(); after tx.commit();

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123527/discussion-between-rohit-gaikwad-and-user2319262).

Answer (score 0):

This is not normal operation in my opinion. 
There is information why :

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12008019/6834892

If you delete all records this sequence further should continue incrementation.